# VirtualBox no network access

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm on a work machine, setting up a virtual ubuntu image using virtual box.

After I installed the image, I can't seem to connect to the internet.

If I look at network and sharing center on my host OS (W7) I see that the VirtualBox Host-Only Network reads as "no network access"

How can I set it up so that it uses the same network as the host OS.

UPDATE!
Okay,  is there a way I can tell virtual box host-only network to use a proxy script?

Comment: What Virtualbox version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a type error in the proxy URL I was given by a co-worker. It is working now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

In Network Settings in VirtualBox choose Bridged Adapter and your physical adapter.
I usually use Intel PRO/1000 MT Server Adapter Type, tend to work in most environments.

Comment: I have the settings matching another virtual image that has no problem connecting to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go into the virtualbox network settings and make sure it's set to something compatible with your connection, then test from within the VM.

Comment: I just saw something on my host network settings that says "Internet connection sharing has been disabled by the network administrator." Would this mean I simply can't do it?